# Stream file changes

Tags: file, stream, dart

How to get a continuously monitoring stream on a File? It seems like File.openRead's stream stops at the end of the file's current state's last byte.

Adding more data to the file no longer triggers the stream's onData.

How to keep the file stream open and manually cancel the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Watching files for changes is platform specific, not something the SDK provides. The watcher package is more general than what you want, but it should be possible to listen for events, and if an event indicates that there's new data, send it to a stream.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/watcher

```
  var watcher = new DirectoryWatcher(path);
  watcher.events.listen((event) {
    print(event);
  });
```